# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

Tags: java

the eclipse tells that lang and i cant find a solution

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2463025552"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:31)

```
String s2[]=s.split("\\,");
Records rec=new Records();
rec.setName(s1[0]);
rec.setAddres(s2[0]);

phone  = Integer.parseInt( s2[1].trim() );
System.out.println(phone);
```

I read from file in this format name-adres,phone and ad in arraylist put for phone i have problem

Answer (score 29):

Integer.parseInt throws a NumberFormatException if the passed string is not a valid representation of an integer. here you are trying to pass **2463025552** which is **out of integer range**.

use long instead

```
long phone = Long.parseLong(s2[1].trim() )
```

Answer (score 16):

The real problem is that a phone number is not an integer. It is a `String`. You should not store it as a number, for reasons similar to the problem you are encountering now. The same applies for ZIP codes, sports team's jersey numbers, and a host of other "fake" numbers.

Comment: +1 to Tom G, using `Long` or other numeric type can cause issues in future.

Comment: This is the correct response. What if the phone number is 000-0001. Do you really want to store it as 1? What would you show the user?

Comment: +1 tom, agreed ... way better to make it an string than long .. sad i dint get that tought while answering :P,

Comment: I tern the int varible to String ?

Answer (score 4):

A Signed 32 Bit Integer can only read upto 2^31. You have to use a bigger datatype. long will get you up to 2^63.

Answer (score 2):

The basic thing is that, we don't need a phone number to be part of a arithmetic calculation like addition, subtraction etc. Hence we can take it as a String safely.

Answer (score 1):

```
2463025552
```

is a out of range for int data type, try giving lesser number. Also check if it is in correct number format (like no spaces etc)

Comment: It is a given phone number, we can't really change it so it fits into an int.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt( s2[1].trim() );` here is your problem. So, change your parsing `Integer` to `Long`

Comment: I change from Integer to long and works perfect..
A lot of thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your data type to long or bigint. Your string is too long then int thats why it have exception..