# Android Studio "uploads" old version of SQLite tables inside my app whenever I run

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've hit a major roadblock developing my first app, and cannot understand what exactly is wrong. I've implemented providers and multiple tables in an app that is basically going to cross-reference tables inside itself. For some reason, even after erasing the app's data on my phone, and uninstalling it, once I run the app from Android Studio it "re-uploads" some of the mock data I was entering in the app to test functionality.

I assume that this prevents me from properly adding the tables that I needed to (which I've tried with no success), since I can get no "clear start" for SQLite... I'm getting crashes whenever I call the Database Helper and Content Providers (whenever I call a cursor) for any of the new tables I've added after the first runs (which version contains the data that keeps magically reappearing within the app)...

*** Update ***

Disabling Google's Auto-Backup feature in the AndroidManifest, and running the app with the device's internet connection disabled (after uninstalling) took care of the "ghost" data. However, now I can see Android Studio is seriously acting up as well, since blocks of code that are commented out are being executed "normally". No point in programming further if I'm not sure what I see is what I'm debugging, and as such I've got absolutely no way of telling how/if my DataBanks are being built as they should... The problem with "managers" below persists.

Here is my logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.scolfaro.multiscreenwallet10, PID: 10461
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scolfaro.multiscreenwallet10/com.scolfaro.multiscreenwallet10.CreditManagerActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "managers"
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "managers"
       at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:443)
       at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:485)
       at android.content.ContentUris.parseId(ContentUris.java:86)
       at com.scolfaro.multiscreenwallet10.data.WalletProvider.query(WalletProvider.java:269)
```

Here is my contract class:

```
public final class CreditManagerContract {

private CreditManagerContract(){}

public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.scolfaro.multiscreenwallet10";

public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

public static final String PATH_MANAGERS = "managers";

public static abstract class CreditManagerEntry implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String CONTENT_LIST_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY
                    + "/" + PATH_MANAGERS;

    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
            ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY
                    + "/" + PATH_MANAGERS;

    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT, PATH_MANAGERS);

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "managers";

    public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COLUMN_TAG = "tag";
    public static final String COLUMN_CLOSE_DATE = "closedate";
    public static final String COLUMN_DUE_DATE = "duedate";
```

This keeps happening, so I'm posting all the lines in the code that lead to the exception. This is the line that actually throws it:

```
selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
```

This is the second line where it points to (in another class):

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
```

This is where the second line gets called (and causes the activity to crash):

```
ArrayList<CreditManager> entries = DbLoader.loadCreditManager(this);
```

Comment: I assume you are inserting that data within the `onCreate` method of the SQLite class?

Comment: Try disabling instant run or clean the build and run again if you are not hard coded the data.

Comment: Yes I am... I've programmed half of the functionality (some 4-5 tables) in one sitting, then planned the rest, tried to wipe everything and added the rest... Every call to any of the new tables results in a crash, while the old ones (even with empty tables) still work... I read through my DbHelper so long that I'm getting depressed ATM XD It all seems right, doesn't work though...

Comment: try uninstalling the entire app data from studio itself. Go to main `menu/Run/Edit Configuration` . Select `app` under` Android Application` on the left. Select `General` tab , click green `+` sing at the bottom 
A drop down will appear, select` Gradle-aware-make` option. Another text box will pop up. enter` :app:uninstallAll` in this text box . Where 'app' is your `app-module` name.    This usually fails when emulator is not connected so relaunch again if it fails. It wipes all the data of specified app in your emulator or connected devices and you should be good.

Comment: Just tried disabling instant run, didn't work...

Comment: post the error log you are getting.

Comment: @Jimmy tried the "Gradle-aware-make" option, crazy tables are still there o.0

Comment: I edited the question to include the contract. Weird thing: I could write to that table before, but trying to read throws NumberFormatException. Since the only place casting is taking place is at the Uri parsing, I assume this has to do with linking the table and the Uri manager in Android, but fixing this seems far beyond what I'm able to grasp (I'm new at this...)...

Comment: I think you should post your relevant code from around WalletProvider.java:269 as well if that is your class.

Comment: @Jimmy will update above...

Comment: ContentUri.parseId `Converts the last path segment to a long`. Are you sure it is valid in your case?

Comment: @Jimmy since I'm defining paths and creating empty tables, then assigning an Uri, I assume it's up to me how I handle them, no?

Comment: BTW I just noticed Android Studio is executing code that's been commented out... This is such a mess :-/

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935167/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string

Comment: @vbp yes, I understand the exception... However, the parsing is done by the Uri handler, which as far as I understand is handled on the OS side (and is actually a long!)... I wonder if it has anything to do with parsing the Id (which normally are ints in Android?) for the Uri with the use of constants in the contract?

Answer (score 0):

Everything sorted, thanks to everybody who contributed (and in the process helped me to learn how to navigate through this invaluable resource we have here).

SO, if you are having this kind of problem ("ghost" data coming back to view), DISCONNECT YOUR TEST DEVICE FROM THE INTERNET because Google defaults to "auto-backup" within apps. This is very damaging when it happens as you are updating/developing your database schemes (it -will- lead to very puzzling crashes, since tables cannot be added after the first implementation of your DBHelper).

Afterwards, go to your AndroidManifest and look for the key enabling auto-backup, and disable it!

Lastly, as for the exceptions pasted here, my noob self FORGOT TO ADD A "break" to the switch at the UriMatcher, which instantly lead to the "default: throw exception" case since there was no break out of the matcher. Live and learn...

I spent the whole afternoon comparing my contract, DbHelper and provider with Google's ContactProvider/Contract/Helper, learned a whole lot, and just saw my beginner mistake after going through the switcher and logs one more time... On to optimizing the noob unstandardized mess my data scheme is right now (after "learning" good DB practices and how they differ from my first-time learning experience)...

Thank you all! I hope someone else profits from my learning curve here...